# How many of this aircraft were manufactured?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, aircraft-identification

What was the total quantity issued of this model aircraft (including any modifications).

[image]

Comment: From the registration ID, this is a Convair CV-340, replacement of the DC3. You may look at the [CV-240 family (240, 340, 440) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_CV-240_family). 312 units of the CV-340 were build.

Comment: You can also work out the model by noting that "The flying dutchman" indicates airline KLM (also marked on the fuselage) and looking at "Fleet History" in the Wikipedia page for KLM. By clicking the links for the various aircraft operated by KLM you'll eventually find a matching aircraft in the "Convair 340" and "Convair 240" operated by KLM from 1953-1964 and 1948-1959 respectively.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick That's how I found it out. On an unrelated note, I don't get why KLM would name its aircraft after a ghost ship.

Comment: @aeroalias, It's not associated with the aircraft, but with the airlines ([sort of slogan](http://taylorempireairways.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/0000-6493-4.jpg)), Now the title of the [airline's flyer](http://luxuryhotelcosmetics.com/app/uploads/2014/09/FD-2014_3_tcm541-538247-1.jpg) and loyalty program. I like [this one](http://media.theiapolis.com/b000000/d19/hLC/i3PLY/r6/s1/t3/wSG/x4HSQ/klm-royal-dutch-airlines-the-flying-dutchman.jpg).

Comment: @aeroalias: The PH-TGI was actually named the "Vincent van Gogh" after the painter. [Source](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/general_aviation/print.main?id=3401674). The [same plane](http://postimg.org/image/n3p25kb1l/)  in different colors, may 1962. The PH-TGI is a Convair 340, according to the [Nieuwe Leidsche Courant](http://leiden.courant.nu/issue/NLC/1953-09-09/edition/null/page/1?query=convair%20ph-tgi&sort=issuedate%20ascending) from September 9, 1953.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aircraft looks like the [Convair CV 440 Metropolitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_CV-240_family) (maybe CV 340) a variant of the CV 240, in operation with the [KLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KLM). According to Wikipedia, a total of 1181 of all the variants were built.

Comment: Apparently is was built as a -340, and in 1955 upgraded to CV-440 specs when it was renamed to the [PH-CGI](http://www.hdekker.info/registermap/MC.htm). Seems fair to treat that as a modification.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for the info. I wasn't sure of that. Thanks for clearing it up.